# Maintain scroll position in listview when clicked

Tags: xaml, listview, scroll, uwp

I am developing an `UWP` app. In my app, I have used a `ListView`. When I click on a listitem, then it navigates me to another page. But when I click back it takes me back to the top of listview. I want it to maintain the scroll position ie. whenever I click back button, it should take me to that listitem which I clicked rather then on the top. Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to set the [`NavigationCacheMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227506) property in XAML or code behind on `Enabled` or `Required`:

```
<Page ...
     NavigationCacheMode="Enabled">
```

or

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

---

If for some reason you're unable to enable the cache, you can use the [`ListViewPersistenceHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewpersistencehelper.aspx) to store the position when leaving the page and restore it when coming back. Shawn Kendrot has a nice [sample](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2015/07/23/Persist-ListView-scroll-position-without-setting-NavigationCacheMode.aspx) on how to do that.